# How to detect, if any other entity/process is writing a file, in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, locking

Please note that, I don't have any control over the target file. Some other process is writing that file. I just want to copy the file when other process completes the write operation.
I was wondering, how i can check the write operation on a file ?

Thanks !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I tell if a file is open elsewhere in C on Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087204/how-can-i-tell-if-a-file-is-open-elsewhere-in-c-on-linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `F_NOTIFY` argument to [`fcntl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl).

Or you can try [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) if you know that you have a Linux kernel >= 2.6.13. I found an [article in Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8478) which describes how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `lsof` command, as follow, for example:

```
lsof | grep myfile
```